# UWP Dialog like the image using C#

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

[image: I want to display a dialog like this]

I tried  Flyout :

```
<AppBarButton Label="About Us" Tapped="appbarButton_Click">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/info.png"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout >
            <TextBlock Text="Hello User" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Flyout>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

However flyouts are always positioned somewhere near the button. So I coudlnt use it.

I tried `MessageDialog`. However they don't occupy full screen width. Nor do they seem to have an option to adjust width.

```
var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello User");
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

I have  zeroed down on `ContentControl` and `ContentDialog`.

```
var cd = new ContentDialog();
cd.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
cd.Content = "Hello User";
await cd.ShowAsync();
```

However even after setting the Horizontal Alignment to stretch the dialog only occupies a portion of the screen.

I want to display a message to the user and in a dialog which occupies the entire screen `width` and partially the `height` (like in the image). If the user clicks outside the dialog, the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and resolved it by using the CustomControl from [callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/tree/master/src/Callisto). You don't need the whole toolkit, just the following classes:

- DynamicTextBlock
- ColorContrastConverter
- CustomDialog
- CustomControlGeneric

From there, you can take every control you like and put it into your dialog, e.g.:
[image]

Comment: Thanks I will be going through it right now.My issue was about displaying a dialog for entire screen width :)

Comment: Thanks dude you are a savior!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user control for this. Set width and height of it to cover full screen and set dialog or whatever you want to in it.